# Spinner changes it is size when adapter set to extended ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I have problem with spinner size when I change it's adapter to Custom Adapter extended from ArrayAdapter.

If I set adapter in standard way, it appears how I set it's style in styles.xml

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);   
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But I have implemented my Custom Adapter for spinner and use it in that way:

```
SpinnerImageAndTextAdapter adapter = new SpinnerImageAndTextAdapter(context, spinnerArray, hasItem, arrayIndex);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my Implemented SpinnerImageAndTextAdapter  class

```
public class SpinnerImageAndTextAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private static final Integer[] imageArray = {R.drawable.ic_orange, R.drawable.ic_green};

private Context context;
private String[] contentArray;
private String[] arrayIndex;
private boolean hasItem;


public SpinnerImageAndTextAdapter(Context context, String[] objects, boolean hasItem, String[] arrayIndex) {

    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, objects);

    this.context = context;
    this.contentArray = objects;
    this.arrayIndex= arrayIndex;

    this.hasItem= hasItem;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

private View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_spinner_item_image_and_text, null);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    textView.setText(contentArray[position]);

    if (hasItem) {
        if (arrayIndex[position].contains("blabla1"))
            textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(imageArray[0], 0, 0, 0);
        else if (arrayIndex[position].contains("blabla2"))
            textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(imageArray[1], 0, 0, 0);
    }


    return convertView;


}
```

Here is my style rules for spinner

```
<style name="XTheme.SpinnerGrayStyleSmall" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_style_gray</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray_darker</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/gray_darker</item>
</style>
```

Question: Is there any way preventing style mismatch after setting custom adapter for spinner?

Comment: I cannot get what you are suffering from. Can you post the actual behavior and the desired behavior?

Comment: Actually when we are using custom adapter for any widget, we have lost multiple things of default style, so its your turn to define your custom style, it will not accept from its **xml**.

Comment: I solved it, adding condition based inflating view on defined getCustomView method. When this method called from overridden getDropDownView method I'm inflating android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item otherwise android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item layout.